# Recreate this pattern with CSS instead of image?

Tags: css

I came across this pattern online but it's an image and I'd like to avoid using images as decoration as much as possible.

Any ideas on how to recreate this pattern? (excluding the background texture behind it)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without cross-browsering, but here's the gist of it:

```
background-color: gray; /* Fallback */
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 35px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 35px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 70px);
```

Taken from **[CSS3 Patterns Gallery](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/)**. Tweak as needed.